# Conversion from byte to string

Tags: java

I want to convert string to byte and again to string from byte like this

`string -> byte -> string`

Example `qwerty -> [B@274b8c21 (byte) -> [B@274b8c21 (string) -> qwerty`

I can not make the last stage:

here my code:

```
public class Converter {
    public static void main(String []args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter word:");
        String text = scan.nextLine();

        byte[] array = text.getBytes();
        String newStr = array.toString();

        String str = new String(array, "UTF-8");

        String newStr2 = array.toString();

        System.out.println("Representation in Byte:     " + array);
        System.out.println("Byte to String:     " + str);
        System.out.println("New Str2:   " + newStr2);


       byte [] newByte = newStr2.getBytes();
        System.out.println("New Byte" + newByte);

        String str2 = new String(newByte, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(str2);
    }
}
```

Comment: what r u trying to achieve by String newStr2 = array.toString();. If u are trying to re-crate the string from byte[] what u have done the previous line is the correct way to go (new String(array, "UTF-8"))

Comment: I make app to android that encrypte and decrypte text.
You enter text to editText #1 and this text converted to string.
String text converted to byte array and this byte array will be displayed in other editText #2. Then from EditText #3 byte array converted to string. I want to convert string from EditText #3
to byte and convert this byte to my text. Program should work like this. This code is the representation of process that I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this `new String (bytearray,charset)` to convert from `byte to String`

```
 System.out.println("New Byte" + new String(newByte),"UTF-8";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String newStr2 = array.toString();
```

This does not create a new String from the `byte[]` instead, it gives a String representation of the `byte[]` array.

The correct way to create a new String from an `byte[]` is

```
String newStr2 =new String(array, "UTF-8");
```

which already seem to have done in this line `String str = new String(array, "UTF-8");`. This is the proper way of creating a new String from a given `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to use UTF-8 as charac-encoding.. If not try by using default.

```
 String s = new String(newByte);
    System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String newStr = array.toString();` It will not display the original string but the byte value

```
String str = "Stackoverflow";
byte[] byt = str.getBytes();

System.out.println("String : " + str);
System.out.println("String in Byte Fromat: " + byt.toString());
System.out.println("String to Byte: " + byt);

String s = new String(byt);
System.out.println("Byte to String : " + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method supported by Java which will directly print **byte Array**.

So You can convert Your encrypted Array to String & print on editText2 like below

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter word:");
    String editText1 = scan.nextLine();

    byte[] array = editText1.getBytes();
    /*
     *  do Your Encryption Here
     */
    String editText2 = new String(array);
    System.out.println(editText2);
```

**Or** if you really want to print the bytes you can do as below

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter word:");
    String editText1 = scan.nextLine();

    byte[] array = editText1.getBytes();
    /*
     *  do Your Encryption Here
     */
    String editText2 = "[";
    for (byte b : array) {
        editText2 += (" " + b + ",");
    }
    editText2 += "]";
    System.out.println(editText2);
```

Printing `array.toString()` always give the **reference** to that **byte array**